# Updating annotations of a PDF using a program coded in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext

I am able to extract annotations present in a PDF page using iTextSharp. However, I am not able to edit these annotations. My requirement is that among multiple annotations I can search a specific annotation and then edit its content and save the PDF. On the opening of the PDF, the updated version should be displayed. However, I tried using `itextsharp`, spire and rasteredge but non-of them give any meaningful result.

Below is the function made using RasterEdge.

```
static void RasterEdit(string PDF)
{
    PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(PDF);
    PDFPage page = (PDFPage)doc.GetPage(0);
    List<IPDFAnnot> annots = PDFAnnotHandler.GetAllAnnotations(doc);
    PDFAnnotHandler.DeleteAnnotation(doc, annots);
    doc.Save(PDF);
    int i = 0;
    Console.Write(" Location where you want to edit tag? ");
    string location = Console.ReadLine();
    location = location.ToUpper();

    Console.Write("New Employee Name: ");
    string emp = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (IPDFAnnot annot in annots)
    {
        i++;
        if (annot is PDFAnnotStickyNote)
        {
            string []txt;
            txt=annot.Content.Split(':');

            /*

             */
            if (txt[0]==location)
            {
                annot.Content = location + ":" + emp; 
            }
        }
       // Console.WriteLine(i+" "+annot.Content);
    }
    PDFAnnotHandler.AddAnnotation(PDF, annots);
}
```

Spire:

```
static void spireEditTag(string PDF)
{

    //Initialize an instance of PdfDocument class and load the file 
    Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument();
    pdf.LoadFromFile(PDF);

    string newfile = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(PDF) + @"\NewPDF.pdf";
    //pdf.SaveToFile(newfile);
    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newfile);

    //PdfPageBase page = pdf.Pages[0];

    //Get the first annotation in the first page 

    Spire.Pdf.Annotations.PdfAnnotation annotation = pdf.Pages[0].AnnotationsWidget[0];

    Console.Write("New Employee: ");
    string emp = Console.ReadLine();
    //Add the modified text and set the formatting 
    annotation.Text = emp;
    //annotation.Color = new PdfRGBColor(Color.Red);
    //annotation.Border = new PdfAnnotationBorder(1f);

    pdf.Pages[0].AnnotationsWidget[0].Text = emp;

    //pdfDocumentViewer1.SaveToFile(fileName);

    //Save the file and view 
    pdf.SaveToFile(PDF,FileFormat.PDF);

    pdf.Close();
    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PDF);

}
```

iTextSharp:

```
static void ReadTagPDF(string PDF)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDF);
    for(int i=1; i<=reader.NumberofPages; i++)
    {
        PdfArray array = reader.GetPageN(i).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if(array==null) continue;
        for( int j=0; j<array.Size; j++)
        {
            PdfDictionary annot = array.GetAsDict(j);
            PdfString text = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if(Convert.ToString(text).Trim()=="1F-MTR-7")
            {
                annot.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString("Test");
                reader.AddPdfObject(annot);
            }
        }
    }
      reader.Close();
}
```

I do not get any error when I run these functions but as well as no change in the annotations of the PDF. If anybody can help out on this, it would be great.

Comment: Of your libraries of choice I'm only somewhat proficient in iTextSharp. In your iTextSharp code, though, you clearly neither try to change anything nor save anything. Thus, it is no wonder it doesn't *give any meaningful result*. Thus, why didn't you change anything there? Furthermore, to help you I'd need a representative source PDF and clear criteria to know which annotations you want to change how.

Comment: @mkl I have updated the iTextSharp Function, it was commented in my script so I forgot to type it in. Although this also doesn't make any difference.

Also, the annotations I am talking about are TextBox Annotations and the Pdf I'm using has it's source path in _string PDF_ . I have all the access rights of the PDF.

Comment: Well, your iTextSharp code still does not save anything: A `PdfReader` really only is a *reader*; if you want to write the contained PDF with your changes, use a `PdfStamper`.

Comment: @mkl can you type in appropriate function for this?

Comment: I am able to change the subject and author of textbox annotations, however not the text content.

Comment: This works for sticky notes annotation though.

 

annots.GetAsDictionary(i).Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Subj, new             iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString("Subject"));
                        annots.GetAsDictionary(i).Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.T, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString("Author"));
                        annots.GetAsDictionary(i).Put(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName.Contents, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString("Bruno Lowagie"));

Answer (score 0):

As of now I haven't been able to find anyway to update or edit the actual PDF Annotation. However, I am utilizing RasterEdge Library to delete the existing annotation and replace it with new content. This works efficiently as it's not taking as much time as I thought. That is the program is quick enough with this logic too.

```
 using RasterEdge.XDoc.PDF;
 static void EditTag(string PDF) 
    {       

        PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(PDF);
        List<IPDFAnnot> annots = PDFAnnotHandler.GetAllAnnotations(doc);
        foreach (IPDFAnnot annot in annots)
        {
            if (annot is PDFAnnotTextBox)
            {
                PDFAnnotTextBox obj = (PDFAnnotTextBox)annot;
                if (obj.Content.Trim() == "Content to be searched and replaced")
                {
                    //  get the 1st page
                    PDFPage page = (PDFPage)doc.GetPage(0);

                    //  create the annotation
                    PDFAnnotTextBox test = new PDFAnnotTextBox();

                    //Copy Properties of Original Annotation
                    test.Boundary = obj.Boundary;
                    test.LineColor = obj.LineColor;
                    test.LineStyle = obj.LineStyle;
                    test.LineWidth = obj.LineWidth;
                    test.Opacity = obj.Opacity;
                    test.TextColor = obj.TextColor;
                    test.TextFont = obj.TextFont;
                    test.FillColor = Color.Yellow;
                    test.TextFont = new System.Drawing.Font(test.TextFont.FontFamily, 6);

                    //Changing the Required Subject and Content of Annotation
                    test.Content = obj.Content + "appending content";

                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting Existing Annotation.");
                    PDFAnnotHandler.DeleteAnnotation(doc, obj);
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleted.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Adding new Annotation.");
                    PDFAnnotHandler.AddAnnotation(page, test);
                    Console.WriteLine("New Annotation added.");

                    //  save the PDF
                    doc.Save(PDF);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```