# How to update Content of annotation

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext

I get the Content of my annotation but I don't know how to update the content and when I generate the pdf it should be the new value

I found this one https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/replacing-pdf-objects but the problem is this is being made in java

```
PdfPage anonPage = pdf.GetPage(1);
PdfDictionary pageDict = pdf.GetPage(1).GetPdfObject();
PdfAnnotation ann   = new PdfTextAnnotation(pageDict);
PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.Annots);
   for (int i = 0; i < annotArray.Size(); ++i)
            {
                PdfDictionary curAnnot = annotArray.GetAsDictionary(i);
                PdfString contents = curAnnot.GetAsString(PdfName.Contents);

            //Gets the value from the comment
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents?.ToString()))
            {
                if (contents.ToString().Contains("Printed"))
                {
                    curAnnot.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString("value has been changed"));
                    Console.WriteLine(contents);
                }
                else
                { Console.WriteLine(contents); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Relevant context for C# code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898949/updating-annotations-of-a-pdf-using-a-program-coded-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hello @DenDelimarsky the one from you send is using itextSharp im just using itext is there any other way?